# iPad 3 - when I click on the email icon, it quickly pulls up the email but then it disappears!

Tags: ipad, email

I click on the email icon as usual, but it just quickly pulls up the email and then disappears.

What's going on?

Comment: Welcome. We have a nice guide on [ask] in case people need more detail to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. Is your device jailbroken? If so, have a go at updating cydia. If not I might need some more information. What did you do before the problem appeared? Have you had the problem for a long time?